# RSQLServer vs. rsqlserver (libraries) name conflict

Tags: r

In my search to find a faster option to query SQLServer, I tested `DBI & RSQLServer` , `RODBC` and new `rClr & rsqlserver` libraries. In my testing `RODBC` seems the fastest and stable. While I experimenting I noticed that installing `rsqlserver` removes `RSQLServer` library probably due to name conflict. If I install `RSQLServer` back, it removes `rsqlserver`. Is it possible to keep them both?

Comment: Libraries aren't removed. Use `packagename::function` to call a function of a specific package.

Comment: `install.packages("RSQLServer", dependencies=TRUE)
library(devtools)
install_github("jmp75/rClr")
find_rtools()
install_github("agstudy/rsqlserver")
library(RSQLServer)` # Last row throws an error?

Comment: @nicola The problem is that the two packages have the same name modulo capitalisation. On Windows, this means they will install into the same directory, so one will overwrite the other.